# How to safely unwrap textField.text and store it safely in an property?

Tags: swift, option-type

I have 6 textfields that I want to at the push of a button concatenate into a string (in order) and then take that string and convert it to an Int.
I know how to convert the string into an Int.

What I keep getting stuck at is how do I create a property under the IBOutlets that is optional and then store the optionally unwrapped textfield.text into the property?

What I have tried is

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
```

this is the IBOutlet

```
var firstTextFieldString: String?
```

that is the property

then later in a function I say

```
func functionName(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == firstTextField {
      if let text = textField.text {
        firstTextFieldString = text
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` property of a `UITextField` is an optional string (`String?`) and can be assigned to any other variables that are of the same type. It looks like your outlet and property are correct.

You should be able to assign the `text` property directly to the `firstTextFieldString` property.

```
firstTextFieldString = firstTextField.text
```

If you want a function to be called when a button is pressed, you can mark the function with `@IBAction` and hook it up in the storyboard.

```
@IBAction func functionName(textField: UITextField) {
    // your function here
}
```

If you reference all your text fields as outlets, you should be able to write a function that directly accesses the text property of each field and combine them together. It depends on exactly what you want to when the text fields have no value. If you want to treat them as empty strings, you could unwrap them with a default value before concatenating them all together.

```
@IBAction func functionName(textField: UITextField) {
    let first = firstTextField.text ?? ""
    let second = secondTextField.text ?? ""
    let third = thirdTextField.text ?? ""
    // etc...
    let result = first + second + third + ...
    // etc...
}
```